# HDR to TIF on Matlab

Tags: matlab, hdr

Good morning,

I have decided to post this new thread because I don't know how to convert a hdr set of images into tif (I don't know if it's possible too with Matlab (usually, I used the  ERDAS image processing software). What I'm trying to do is the following:

```
myFolder= 'G:\HDR\2'
filePattern = fullfile(myFolder, '*.hdr');
hdrFiles = dir(filePattern);

for k = 1:length(hdrFiles)
  baseFileName = hdrFiles(k).name;
  fullFileName = fullfile(myFolder, baseFileName);

  hdr = hdrread(fullFileName);
  rgb = tonemap(hdr);
  hdrwrite (hdr, filename) % I don't know how to indicate .TIF on that part
end
```

I don't know how to convert the hdr files into tif. After doing this, the error is the following:

```
Error using hdrread>readHeader (line 62)
Not a Radiance file.

Error in hdrread (line 29)
fileinfo = readHeader(fid);
```

May be something wrong on the code or it is not possible to convert that files using Matlab?

Thanks in advance everyone! Any kind of help will be grateful!

Comment: [hdrwrite](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/images/ref/hdrwrite.html) writes hdr files. You could convert the hdr to an RGB using [tonemap](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/images/ref/tonemap.html), and use [imwrite](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html) to write the tif file.

Comment: After saving as tif, you also won't be able to use [hdrread](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/images/ref/hdrread.html) to open the file, as it only opens hdr files. You'll need to use [imread](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/imread.html?searchHighlight=imread).

Comment: Thanks 2cents for your help! I've ended the code with that part (imwrite(rgb, fullFileName)) but I still receive the same message: Not a Radiance file.

Error in hdrread (line 29)
fileinfo = readHeader(fid);

Comment: Is line 29 where you read in the hdr file? If that is the case, your hdr format may not be the same as Matlab's hdr format. How do you produce your hdr images?

Comment: With the fmask tool (https://code.google.com/p/fmask/)!

Comment: The fmask tool does not appear to make a hdr image. It's primary output XXXFmask is a mask identifying land, water, snow, and clouds. If this is the file that you are trying to save, I would simply use the [`save`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) or [`imwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html) functions. If you want to make an hdr image, I would try [`makehdr`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/makehdr.html).

Comment: Thanks! I have converted previously the format hdr to tif with other software because I still don't know how to work with it.

Answer (score 0):

For JPEG, its is a low dynamic range format.
So if you are creating a High Dynamic Range image, you don't want to save it in a Low Dynamic Range format.
You want to save it in a format that can contain the full dynamic range (TIFF, PSD/PSB, EXR, HDR, etc.).

You can apply tone mapping to convert the HDR image to LDR, then save it as an LDR format.
But it is no longer an HDR image.
 try out this editor if you are using mac os [macphun](http://macphun.com/tonality) and good luck!